# How can I change the Xamarin components folder?

Tags: xamarin, compilation, xamarin.forms

I am running into an error 
Expecting class path separator ';' before 'ye\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar'' in argument number 2   SampleBrowser.Droid_2017
D:\Forms\SampleBrowser\SampleBrowser.Droid\CREATEMULTIDEXMAINDEXCLASSLIST

This seems to be happening because my windows user is "alur'ye"
THe apostrophe in the name is being included as part of the path and is upsetting something in the compilation.

As this is my domain user I cannot change it.  Is there any way I can move these components to a different path?

I know that my problem is not the "Android SDK path" issue reported in many other threads.

After switching users the problem goes away.  Unfortunately working as a local user, and not a domain user on the machine is not an option for me

Comment: It's possible that can cause the issue, but from my experience it's because your Android SDK is on a path with a space seperation. Please try to move that first before this.

Comment: Mine is set to "d:\android\android-sdk".  I don't think most people have this problem.  You can also see the error begins exactly on the apostrophe